# "No bootable devices found" after formating SD card by $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4MB

Tags: boot, partitioning, dd

I was trying to format my -4GB- SD card, as I failed to format it directly, I found that I can zero out it by:

```
sudo unmount /dev/sda 
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4MB
```

After running these commands, I stopped the process as it take too much time, after a while my browser stopped and I couldn't open it again, then I tried to log out and sign in again to get it working again, but my laptop froze this time so I did force shutdown.. then I turned it on again but each time I get

```
No bootable devices found
```

How can I get my laptop working again without losing my data?

......

laptop model: Dell Inspiron 5559

Installed OSes: Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, you've met the fabled **D**isk **D**estroyer, Eater of Data.

I'm going to assume you only have a single actual hard drive in your computer, present at `/dev/sda`.

When you unmounted `/dev/sda` (which does nothing, by the way), you were targeting your computer's hard drive. Same with the command that broke everything. Let's break it down:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4MB
```

In this command, you're overwriting `/dev/sda` (your hard drive) with `/dev/zero` (or no data). This is what is called a Dangerous Idea, and is why you should *really* triple-check your `dd` commands. Any data that was erased is now gone forever with zero hope of recovery.

Now, you could possibly use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (works on non-photos, too!) to recover any files that were possibly spared from being destroyed by this command, but you will no longer be able to recover everything. If you do try `photorec`, use a live image, and don't touch your drive.

Comment: Thanks for replaying Kaz. I don't have a single drive, actually I have  4 drivers. I found (using [Disks] in ubuntu) that my 4GB present at /dev/sda, so I use it in my command as a desired driver to be wiped. I don't know why my other drives! .. any help?

Comment: @KamalMoussa You have four drives in a laptop? That seems strange... What were the sizes (and names) of the other three, if you can remember them?

Comment: sorry I got confused, I mean 4 partions.

Comment: @KamalMoussa Okay, that makes more sense. I still have a bit of trouble believing that `/dev/sda` was your SD card, though. Are you sure your system actually detected it?